# Optimizing projection for accuracy in calculating distances

Tags: coordinate-system, mercator, projection-mathematics

I receive a set of LatLong points and I want to optimize the projection to Euclidean points so as to try to keep (distance in Euclidean space)/(greater circle distance in latLong) with variance as low as possible.

The Mercator projection error in distances (east/west stretching) increases as you get farther from the equator. Is it common to calculate the projection with a different latitude than then equator as the "center"? If yes any methods/material on this?

The set of LatLong points has varying latitudes but always has a |minLat - maxLat| < 10

Usually the radius of a circle containing the points is 100km and not exceeding 10,000km. I do not expect the projection/process to work as well when the points are more spread out.

Comment: How big an area are you usually working with?

Comment: @mkennedy I edited the question. Hope it clarifies